# How to insert object using KnexJS?

Tags: knex.js

I have 2 tables in SQL , i use [KnexJS](http://knexjs.org/)  to inset data.

I use "[batchInsert](http://knexjs.org/#Utility-BatchInsert)" utility to insert object to one table.

my question:

Let say that my tables is :

1. Product
2. Product_meta

Can i insert this object to both of tables in on KnexJS call:

```
let products =
[{
    SKU: 'A',
    title: 'product A',
    product_meta: [
        { key: '_price', value: 20 },
        { key: '_qty', value: 10 }
    ]

}, {
    SKU: 'B',
    title: 'product B',
    product_meta: [
        { key: '_price', value: 9 },
        { key: '_qty', value: 50 }
    ]

}];
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to do a separate insert for both of the tables. Knex doesn't know anything about SQL relations.

With objection.js (which is based of knex) it can be done if the relation mappings are declared correctly.